Shutdown Issues DRV8251
I am attempting to use a PSoC 6 (CY8CKIT-062-BLE Product Page) and Texas Instruments DRV8251 (Product Page) to drive a brushed DC motor. I have created a small driver board that interfaces with the PSoC 6, schematic and layout like so:


I am experiencing an issue where the trip current seems to be much lower than anticipated. Per the the DRV8251 datasheet, this current can be calculated by dividing the reference voltage by 10 times the sensing resistor value (R7, 0.33 Ohms). The reference voltage is 3.3V, created by the voltage divider of R9 and R8 from 5V. This should create a trip current of approximately 1A. From testing though, it seems the driver chip is tripping at approximately 100mA. We verified the reference voltage is around 3.3V, and the value of the current sensing resistor is the anticipated 0.33 Ohms. We also attempted running the board without the sensing resistor (ISEN pin connected directly to ground) which would theoretically allow the chip to output up to 3.5A of current, but we are still experiencing tripping at ~100mA.
This is a very similar design to a driver board we created for the PSoC 3, which I have not experienced any issues with.
Any help or explanation for why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

That Vref looks like it could use a decoupling capacitor.

R9 and R8 are not connected as a voltage divider. R9 is just a load at 5 V and R8 is in series with the REF input.

You have the same issue with R2/R11 and R1/R10: They are not voltage dividers. R1 and R2 are just pullups to 5 V.

As others have mentioned, your voltage dividers are a little off. Your original reference voltage divider, for example, should look more like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage has to drop 1.66667V over the 1kOhm resistor prior to being used for Vref in your case.
